# Arrow keys in Xcode 6 not working

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I have the weirdest issue with Xcode 6 on OS X Yosemite. For some reason I can't use the left and right arrow keys anymore to navigate within my source code. Instead, the system beep sound would come up. Up and down arrows work fine.

I'm afraid it could have something to do with my fiddling around with the key bindings. In only changed the ones for block (de)indentation though (originally CMD+[, changed to TAB), so in my understanding the arrow keys shouldn't be affected at all.

Comment: Does the keyboard work OK with other apps?  I know I get "cannot detect keyboard type" on my Late 2013 iMac with Yosemite beta 1 & 2...

Comment: The keyboard works perfectly (I can use the very arrow keys inside this comment text field). It worked in Xcode until yesterday, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work again by running

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

in the terminal and then restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you created a conflict when customizing your key bindings.

To fix that, in Xcode settings (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), go to `Key Bindings` tab and make sure your `Move Left` and `Move Right` commands are not empty under the `Customized` tab. If they are, just select them and hit <kbd>⌫</kbd>.