# Xcode page jumps randomly when use return, page up/down and arrow keys

Tags: xcode

When I use page up/down and arrow up/down the page will jumps to some random position.
For example:

1. at line 2000, hit page up
2. the page jumps to line 50 (the cursor is
   still at line 1950 for example)
3. hit arrow up key
4. page jumps back to line 1949...

Basically any key that moves the page, will randomly trigger the page jump issue, but cursor remain correct position and page scrolls back when use any key move the page again...

This is so irritating, I've tried remove all Xcode settings to original and no use...

Thanks for help!

Comment: When you say "page up" what does that mean? What kind of keyboard? Have you looked to see what function that key is bound to?

Comment: page up key, non-apple keyboard. but forget about page up, use arrow up same result... jumps randomly...

Comment: Check the key bindings in Xcode and keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences:Keyboard:Shortcuts. Also see this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24638061/451475)

Comment: @Zaph not working as I already removed all customizations. But I feel it may related to emojis in the .m file, happens quite a lot on a single file, whole project is in Dropbox folder (but moving out from Dropbox folder still got this issue), this .m file got quite a lot of emojis, but removing the emoji seems helped reduce the change just a little bit, so all in all still cannot find the cause. but this .m file even auto-suggest take longer time than other .m files...