# xcode jumps from one row to other

Tags: ios, xcode

When I edit some swift file.
Xcode jumps from one row to other.
Example I edit row 800 . Xcode jumps to row 100. So I am not able to see what is in editing row anymore. I am not able to see this part of swift file. I can see only rows 100-300. I can jump after I press some button on keyboard.
At the top a warning is appearing

**Xcode encountered a problem. Source editor functionality is limited. Attempting to restore...**

This answer do not help [Arrow keys in Xcode 6 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631146/arrow-keys-in-xcode-6-not-working/24638061#24638061)